# Issues creating a subclass that pulls variables from super() class

Tags: python, class, subclass, super

I'm a little bit new to python and I'm currently practicing classes, subclasses and the super() method.
I've been creating a small RPG (or at least the base concept) in Python and I've created the base class and can't seem to pull the data in a subsclass.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class base_human:
    def __init__(self, health, magic, speed):
        self.health = health
        self.magic = magic
        self.speed = speed

## Is the base class

class Warrior(base_human):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(self, health, magic, speed)

## Is my sub class

base_human = base_human(10, 10, 10)

Brian = Warrior("Brian")

print(Brian.health)
print(Brian.name)

## Is the final print to test.
```

I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zuikis/Desktop/PI Projects/Classes/RPG 2.py", line 48, in <module>
    Brian = Warrior("Brian")
  File "/Users/zuikis/Desktop/PI Projects/Classes/RPG 2.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, health, magic, speed)
NameError: name 'health' is not defined
```

Grateful for any help and forgive me if I've made a mistake in the format of the post, any further advice would be well received. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

The `Warrior.__init__()` method needs to take all the parameters that `base_human.__init__()` takes, so that it can pass them along when it calls `super().__init__()`.

```
class Warrior:

    def __init__(self, name, health, magic, speed):
        super().__init__(health, magic, speed)
        self.name = name
```

Then you need to provide all those values when you create a `Warrior`:

```
Brian = Warrior("Brian", 10, 20, 5)
```

On the other hand, if Warriors all start with the same attributes, you could hard-code them in the `super()` call.

```
class Warrior:

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(10, 20, 5)
        self.name = name
```

Comment: Thanks for this, after reading through the code a few more times and a bit of experimenting I got my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, where does your human class get its health, magic and speed from?

Exactly, it doesn't get them and that's why it is complaining. Your warrior class should have

```
def __init__(self, name, health, magic, speed):
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the class definition

```
class Warrior(base_human):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(self, health, magic, speed)
```

Where are you passing `health` or `magic` or `speed` from? No where. None of them are defined. You need to write

```
class Warrior(base_human):
    def __init__(self, name, health, magic, speed):
        super().__init__(health, magic, speed)
        self.name = name
```